# How to pass object from array and another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to update the data in local db based upon the response from the server but i am getting lot of data from the server which is not needed for local db so i have manually deleted those unwanted values but i would like to do this in a dynamic way. so i have taken the columns name from local db using pragma and i compared the values which i got from the server with the names which i had stored in the array.But i would like to store the key and value in a object.can anyone tell me how to do it?

```
columns = ['id', 'name', 'category'];
category = {id: 122, name: 'ABD', category: 'Food', created_at: '2014-05-20', is_deleted: 'false'};
```

I need the result as:
  var data = {id: 122, name:'ABD', category: 'Food'};

Code:

```
for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
          $log.log('Merged data is', value.category[columns[j]]);
          $log.log('Data is', data);
        }
```

Comment: Using reduce is good for this type of thing eg. -> `columns.reduce((a,v)=>(a[v]=category[v]) && a,{})`  ps, if you don't mind using ES6, and you want me to explain how this works, let us know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the array and check if the element is a property in the object. If not then you can delete that property from the object.

```
for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
      if(category[columns[j]] === undefined){
        delete category[columns[j]];
      }
}
```

**Edit:**

As asked in comments, if you don't want to delete the properties you can create a new object with the required properties:

```
var data = {};
for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
    data[columns[j]] = category[columns[j]];
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: but i don' t want to delete the extra one i need to take values for the columns available in local db.

Comment: Hi @Nidhinkumar please check now  if it solves your purpose or not and accept the answer if it does.

Answer (score 0):

A lodash one-line solution if you like:

```
var data = _.map(category , _.partialRight(_.pick, ['id', 'name', 'category']));
```

lodash docs here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4